# Firebase cloud functions incrementing queue number

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a Flutter Restaurant application where each restaurant has a cloud firestore document and it in a field called queueNumber this value starts at 1 and with every order it increases by 1.

I'm trying to make sure each order has a unique queue number. I have a cloud function that triggers whenever a new document created in the orders collection. Here is the following code.

```
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

        const orderData = snapshot.data();
        const id = orderData.id;

        if (orderData && orderData.restaurantId != null)  {
          
            return restDoc.update({
                queueNumber: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
            })
        }

    });
```

So the user places an order with the existing queueNumber in the restaurant document. Than the cloud function increments the queueNumber so the next request has a queueNumber that is 1 higher than the previous.

Here is the problem: Sometimes when two orders are placed one after another they get the same queueNumber. The end result in restaurant document is correct but the individual orders get the wrong number (ex: Order 1 has 51 Order 2 has 51 Restaurant document has 53)

Is there a way to fix this method or a better approach to handle the queue numbers
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into a race condition between each of the clients that's adding a document.  Firestore doesn't offer a built-in way to ensure that a field is unique, nor does it offer a way to automatically and safely set a value of a field based on the contents of other documents.  This wouldn't scale in the way that Firestore requires.

You should first find a way to implment your app without increasing numbers like this.  Check if maybe a timestamp is a better way to track the time order in which documents are added.  That will scale much better.

If you absolutely need increasing numbers like this, you will have to involve a whole new document just to track the latest number assigned, and use that document in a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) when adding new documents.  The transaction will have to:

1. Read the counter document
2. Increment the count value in memory
3. Create the new document with this value
4. Also update the counter document with this value

All of this must be done within the transaction, or will not be safe.